# ElasticSearch - indexing only the modified documents using java code

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Am indexing a large number of records (200k) from Oracle to ElasticSearch using Java Code. Am able to index it properly. Now, if there is any records are modified in my Oracle database then, that modified records also need to be indexed in ElasticSearch.

So, for that instead of indexing entire records how can I index only the modified records. Is there any feature in elastic search where it can identify only the modified documents and an index that specific documents alone.

Am getting my Oracle database records via webservices.

Comment: Are you migrating the entire set of records from Oracle db to ElasticSearch? If thats the case are looking for this record to get updated in ES when there is an update in Oracle db ?

Comment: @vizsatiz- Yes, both should be in sync.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the approach that you are looking for but I can give you some idea on where you can start. I haven't worked in Oracle db much but I have experience working on MySQL. MySQL has `binlog` which tracks are the operations done on the db, I hope there must be something of the similar lines in Oracle db (which I am gonna call `binlong` in the context of this answer). You can use this  `binlog` to track the operations and then sync to the same to your ES cluster.

To sync things to your ES cluster, ES has exposed its create, update, delete and read APIs.

Adding an open source lib for parsing `binlog` for MySQL: https://github.com/zalora/binlog-parser

Hope this helps !!